# Plotly.kt Shows Image in Tooltip Hover

Tags: plotly, kotlin-multiplatform

I am using Plotly.kt in a Kotlin/JS application and I want to show image, video and another chart when hovering on a data point on the graph. According to [this](https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/tooltip#using-urls-to-load-images-and-text-in-tooltips), it is possible to disable the default hover by setting `hoverinfo = none`. However, I did not find a way to listen to the `hover event`. Could anyone help on this?

Comment: The tooltip component you are referring to is a dash core component used in dash application, which uses Plotly.js as plotting backend. I'm not familiar with Plotly.kt, but it also relies on Plotly.js and is supposed to preserve its original (JS) API. All this to say that you probably want to focus on Plotly.js events directly, and use JS to bind a handler to the `plotly_hover` event. See https://plotly.com/javascript/hover-events/

Comment: I tried to add an event listener to the ```div``` and ```Document``` to capture the ```plotly_hover``` event, but I haven't had it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `plot div` object of PlotlyJS implements the `.on()` method for processing the PlotlyJS event, which is discussed in [here](https://plotly.com/javascript/plotlyjs-events/). However, the `.on()` method is not wrapped in Plotly.kt. So, a temporary solution is to treat the `plotDiv` as dynamic, so that the `.on()` method can be used without compilation error. Or, use the `js()` function to run the Javascript code directly.

The following is adapted from this [official example](https://github.com/SciProgCentre/plotly.kt/blob/master/examples/js-demo/src/main/kotlin/space/kscience/plotly/jsdemo/main.kt).

```
private fun drawDeserialization(element: HTMLElement): Unit {
    val plot = Plotly.plot {
        scatter {
            x(1, 2, 3, 4)
            y(10, 15, 13, 17)
            mode = ScatterMode.markers
            type = TraceType.scatter
            hoverinfo = "none"
        }
    }
    val serialized = plot.toJsonString()
    val deserialized = Plot(Json.decodeFromString(MetaSerializer, serialized as String).toMutableMeta())

    element.append.plotDiv(plot = deserialized)

    // option 1: Get synamic reference to the plotDiv object
    val pdiv: dynamic = element?.firstElementChild
    pdiv.on("plotly_click") { event -> alert("Caught Hovering Event!") }

    // option 2: Run the Javascript code directly
    js("pdiv.on('plotly_click', function() {alert('Caught Hovering Event!');})")
}
```